# How can I deploy my Python web app or turn it into an executable?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, executable

I've tried a ton of different ways of deploying my web app, and it seems that every method has an issue. I've programmed a lot before, but only for personal projects that were ran through command lines. This is my first time trying to put together a python web app using flask. I want to deploy it or turn it into an executable, but it seems that every single method I try has an issue.

I tried using Heroku, but the slug size was too big (2.4GB, to a max of 500MB). I checked the dependencies, and it is mainly this large because of Torch and PyTorch. I was told to use .gitignore and various other methods, but I don't know what exactly I could ignore in order to ensure that this program still works.
I also tried using AWS, both with elastic beanstalk and with amplify, and neither worked. The former had the same issue as Heroku, even after I tried increasing the volume size. The latter just didn't work at all.
I tried using pyinstaller to make an executable, but whenever I do, it results in an error where 'Lightning' can't be found. It makes the executable, but this error arises whenever I double click it to run.
This is the repo for my files, please let me know if there's anything I can do. Also, as a new programmer, I'm open to learning anything necessary for this to work, as I've been learning as I go. I'll take any and all criticism.

https://github.com/aarnavgautam/speakscript

Also, I'm on MacOS, but I have a PC with Windows 11 as well if that can help with anything.